# много файлов *.class

Tags: java

Я извиняюсь, за свой вопрос...

В результате компиляции некоторого файла, допустим, -- myProga.java, внутри которого прописано три класса (C1, C1 и C3), на выходе получается три файла с именами, C1.class, C2.class и C3.class.

Меня беспокоит, а что если прога будет состоять из нескольких десятков классов? Ведь тогда будет создано несколько десятков файлов классов. Я думаю, это не самый лучший способ создания программ.

Единственное средство, которое я пока нашёл -- это использование пакетов. Но, механика пакетов такова, что она не объединяют файлы классов, а всего лишь растаскивает их по поддиректориям. Иначе говоря, как было огромное количество файлов, так оно и осталось.

Чего я хочу? Я бы хотел видеть после компиляции один файл, как это осуществляется в С/С++. Ну или хотя бы несколько штук. Но не десятки, раскиданные по поддиректориям!

Возможно, я чего-то не понимаю. Я не Java-программист, я -- Си-шник. Я всего пятый день читаю книжку по java.

Прошу выдать мне волшебный пендель в правильном направлении. Спасибо!

Comment: Обычно эти классы и пакеты упаковываются в единый файл, например, jar.

Comment: Вы, как сишник, знакомы с объектными файлами, я полагаю... :) Так вот здесь похожая ситуация, просто вместо компоновщика (линкера) подобие архиватора.

Comment: В IntelliJ IDEA, например, чтобы собрался jar'ник из файлов вашего проекта вам потребуется [добавить артефакт сборки](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/configuring-artifacts.html), а затем его собрать (`Build/Build Artifacts...`).

Comment: Ага, понял! Далее сам разберусь. (По иронии -- в предыдущем вопросе товарищ как раз спрашивает про проблему с jar-ом.) Всем спасибо! Вопрос можно считать закрытым.

Comment: @ЖевакАлександрАнтонович Мне кажется, что это довольно востребованный вопрос среди начинающих java-программистов и не стоит его закрывать. Просто нужно чтобы кто-нибудь по-человечески расписал все в ответе (пригодится другим).

Answer (score 3):

Попробую успокоить по поводу большого числа файлов.
Хорошо это или плохо, но создатели java решили использовать плоскую модель классов где каждый класс и интерфейс компилируеся в отдельный файл. Это касается как нормальных классов так и анонимных классов.   В основе такого решения,  я думаю,  было упрощение реализации загрузчика классов. Если бы несколько классов записывались в один файл тогда,  для того чтобы найти и загрузить класс, загрузчик должен или просматривать все файлы или иметь таблицу с путями для каждого класса. С плоской структурой,  путь к файлу класса строится просто из имени класса и пакета. (Для анонимных классов немного сложнее) 
 В java 8 с добавлением лямбда, количество файликов резко увеличилось потому как каждое выражение также компилируется в отдельный файл. Внутри, лямда это тот-же анонимный класс.

Вообщем-то, десятки и даже тысячи файлов .class это нормально,  и  java работает с ними достаточно быстро.    В повседневной жизни работать с файлами классов приходится очень редко. В основном программы и библиотеки упаковываются в jar,  war и ear архивы.  В ручную никто не компилирует java классы,  для этого используются средства автоматизации такие как ant и maven.